# Signal Label Propagation in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I would like to follow the propogation of a signal in simulink in different subsystems in my M-script.

In the following example

[image]

I would like to be able to retrive the name *In1* on the Inport block when i am out side the subsystem *Subsystem*. I am intresting as well in the oppsit situation, assuming i am inside subsystem *Subsystem*. I would like to be able to retrive the signal name  which is outside *Subsystem*.

Comment: I assume you have looked at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/signal-label-propagation.html. For your question about retrieving `In1` outside the subsystem, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @am304, wouldn't there be a way (rather complicated for sure) to create a mask parameter (say `SignalName`) for `Subsystem`, find the name of the signal and use `set_param` to name and assign it to `SignalName`?

Comment: Maybe, you can give it a try. I am not convinced though.